# String manipulation in Python docstrings

Tags: python, string, documentation

I've been trying to do the following:

```
#[...]
    def __history_dependent_simulate(self, node, iterations=1,
                                     *args, **kwargs):
        """
        For history-dependent simulations only:
        """ + self.simulate.__doc___
```

What I tried to accomplish here is to have the same documentation for this private method as the documentation of the method `simulate`, except with a short introduction. This would allow me to avoid copy-pasting, keep a shorter file and not have to update the documentation for two functions every time.

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know of a reason why, or whether there is a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A better solution is probably to use a decorator, eg:

```
def add_docs_for(other_func):  
    def dec(func):  
        func.__doc__ = other_func.__doc__ + "\n\n" + func.__doc__
        return func
    return dec

def foo():
    """documentation for foo"""
    pass

@add_docs_for(foo)
def bar():
    """additional notes for bar"""
    pass

help(bar) # --> "documentation for foo // additional notes for bar"
```

That way you can do arbitrary manipulations of docstrings.

Comment: Arbitrary manipulation means you could do have "SEE DOCS FOR >foo<" in the docstring, and have the decorator use re to replace that with foo.__doc__, eg.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) makes it pretty clear:

> **What is a Docstring?**
>
> A docstring is a string literal that
>   occurs as the first statement in a
>   module, function, class, or method
>   definition. Such a docstring becomes
>   the **doc** special attribute of that
>   object.

So, it's not an expression that evaluates into a string, it's a *string literal*.